# IOS::We found that your app falls into a category of apps that is often used for illegal file sharing

Tags: ios, app-store

> Reasons
>      22.4: Apps that enable illegal file sharing will be rejected
>
> ----- 22.4 -----
>
> We found that your app falls into a category of apps that is often used for illegal file sharing, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, the app allows users to share music. Please see the attached screenshot/s for more information.
>
> We encourage you to review your app concept and evaluate whether you can incorporate different content and features that are in compliance with the Guidelines.
>
> For app design information, check out the videos: "The Ingredients of Great Apps" and “Designing User Interfaces for iPhone and iPad Apps,” available on the iOS Developer Center, and the iOS Human Interface Guidelines in particular, the sections, "Great iOS Apps Embrace the Platform and HI Design Principles" and "Human Interface Principles".
>
> Screenshot_1.png
>      Screenshot_2.png

I got this error form the App Store. How can I resolve it? I am getting the iTunes music file and sharing it to Mail, Messages and Airdrop. What is the reason? I am also getting the MPMediaArtwork. The artwork, song names and songs play while showing in the table cell after I take the screen shot from my device.

Comment: Maybe its because you are taking apple copyrighted music from iTunes as you say here: `I am getting the iTunes music file`. You are then sharing it: `and that files sharing to the Mail,Message and Airdrop` hence `Illegal File Sharing`

Comment: Thanks for replaying.How to detect the copyrighted music from iTunes.

Comment: generally speaking all music downloaded from iTunes is only licensed to play on that persons device or devices that belong to that account. You cant share it.

Comment: Before sharing I'm converting the Documentdirectory url with export type of ".MP3", after conerting into the NSData.That data send to the mail,message and airdrop.It's playing fine.but I don't know how to rectify the app store issue.

Comment: Apps where apple cant verify you are authorized to share it (which are almost none) they wont let you share those files.

Comment: Im not a legal authority but usually when you buy an app or an MP3 its for you only. Unless you have performed the music yourself, you don't have the license to share it with someone else. Think of it this way: Suppose you tell your friend to loan you his laptop. He gives it to you and says its ok to use this however long you need it but you cant let anyone else use it. This doesn't mean you can give it to your friends to use. Same concept except that iTunes is giving you the permission to listen to it on your iDevices and you alone.

Comment: My App main aim is sharing the music files.What i do.

Comment: Sorry dude but your app will never make it into the app store if you are attempting to share music it isn't allowed simple as. You'll have to rethink your requirements and design a lot by the sounds of it.

Comment: Please see this link:: http://kymatica.com/Software/AudioShare.In this they are sharing the iTunes music files also.How is it possible please suggest me.And What i need to implement.

Comment: sorry for above link actual link is this::https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audioshare-audio-document/id543859300?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got solution.If we downloaded the songs from iTunes.That Playlist is coming under the playlist's.Like this  Pic.In this we are easily find out Which songs are copy righted[Purchased songs] "**That play list name is-->**"**Purchased**   After we can easily remove from Tableview based on the "**MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName**"but your problem is solved in Only **Playlist's**
And remaining tabs means **Artist** and **Albums** Particularly Purchased songs **MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL** url coming nil based on this one also we can rectify the easily.sorry for grammar mistakes.It's working for me.
 [image]

Comment: That solves not violating the copyright on songs purchased via iTunes. But that does not solve the overall copyright of songs, consider that essentially all songs are copyrighted so you will still be violating their copyright. You must assume any work including songs are copyrighted. The writers and performers deserve the money from the sale of their songs, you are stealing from them if you share their works without their explicit permission.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty clear what the message is saying: You can't create any application that shares files. iTunes files are copyrighted so that only the user who downloads it can listen to it (exception being another device on your same iTunes account). I assume from the above text you want to stay away from file sharing all together.

Apple is very serious about potential copyright issues so this type of application is clearly not allowed. My recommendation is view the Apple documentation and find an app idea that does not conflict with your Apple policies. Though it is unfortunate that your hard work wont be able to make it to the app store, its always a risk you take when building an app. Apple can reject it for any reason, including : "We don't find this app to be useful", although this bar appears to be set pretty low.

You can always contact Apple and ask them if there is a way to do file sharing that complies with their policies, but my understanding of the policies is that simply, you cant do it. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Please see this link::https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audioshare-audio-document/id543859300?mt=8 in this they are sending the iTunes music files also.suggest me.

Comment: It says it supports iTunesSharing which means this: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094

Comment: Sir,iCloud songs means these are purchased songs or copy righted songs or noraml songs also  is there in icloud?Please help me out.